# How to make python faster?

Tags: python, c++, performance

I'm working on a python project which is required to do a lot of tasks in the shortest amount of time.

Done some tests, and a `print("Hello World!")` takes about 0.7 seconds to run with python.

In c++, `cout<<"Hello World!";` takes about 0.003 seconds, a huge difference compared to python.

What approach should I take to minimize python's run time? How should I compile the code?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, it's not compiled and will, theoretically at least, always be slower than a compiled language like C++. That being said, you can invoke C functions from Python. For example, numpy is written is C.

Comment: The question is too broad. Profile your code and figure out where the bottleneck is. Then try to optimize or ask about that part of the program specifically. It is unlikely in most cases that the time taken up by output is relevant.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to compile any code. Even a simple `print("Hello World!")` function.

Comment: @MateiPiele There is a module called `CPython`.

Comment: You can make a [C extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c) with a function that calls `printf`. Then you can install it with Python or even rebuild Python so that the C extension module acts like a built-in standard module. Though even if you have a C extension module, it wouldn't be as fast because Python needs to translate `printf` in a Python script to your function. So there is that additional step.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this question has to do with `C++` unless you are looking to be told to rewrite your program in `C++` :-)

Comment: There's something wrong with your computer / Python setup if *print('Hello world!')* is taking 0.7s

Comment: @Galik What happens if you execute `print` in good-old terminal?

Comment: I'm getting about 1.02 seconds with `timeit.timeit("devnull.write('Hello, world!')", setup='import os; devnull=open(os.devnull, "w")', number=10_000_000)` and about 0.8 sec with a loop like `for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) std::cout << "Hello, world!";` in C++. So, Python isn't much slower here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question but shows (proves?) that there must be something wrong with OP's Python runtime setup / environment

```
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
print('Hello world!')
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Duration={end-start:6f}s')
```

**Output:**

Duration=0.000018s

Comment: Used the same thing: results vary from 0.0001s to 0.9s